# 503 service unavailable after installing php-fpm with apache and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

I have installed apache on centos 7 and setup `nginx` as a reverse proxy for apache. `Apache` listens into `8080` and `nginx` into `80`. I have two virtual hosts and also two server blocks.

Everything is **OK** and I can see my two server addresses: `www1.mysite.com` and `www2.mysite.com`

Now I install `php-fpm` to run `php script`. Near to one of my tested index.html files in my websites' `root directory`, I create an `info.php` file to see something printed by php. But I encounter a **503 error** (unavailable service). What is wrong with my simple configuration do you think?

Any idea or similar experience would help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

My problem was almost funny. I had named my sock file php-fpm.sock but it was another name in the php-fpm config file.
I made them equal and the problem was resolved. Hope nobody encounter this rediculous mistake.

Comment: ha.. same thing happened to me. I double checked after reading your comment thinking "it cannot be that, I already looked".. and yet.. :D weird because it worked before I moved the webroot and setup a symlink.. and it worked a few minutes ago.. no idea what I did.`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`